# How to get inference using Jena command line tool 'sparql'?

Tags: sparql, jena

A
|_P(p1,p2)
|  |_M(m1,m2)
|
B

I want to get the A's all instances.

my query is

```
SELECT ?x
    WHERE { 
            ?x rdf:type :A .}
```

Output:
A(p1,p2,m1,m2)

**How to get this result using command line tool 'sparql'?**.  Means I want to get inference here.

My OWL file is here:

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11"/>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#A">
    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#B">
    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#M">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#P"/>
    </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#P">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#A"/>
    </owl:Class>

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#m1">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#M"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#m2">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#M"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#p1">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#P"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#p2">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#P"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: "command line tool 'sparql'"? Which command line tool is that, exactly?

Comment: If I execute this query without reasoner then i use this code from cmd.....

sparql --data owl file name --query query text file or 



e.g. sparql --data demo.owl --query query.text

Comment: This is not a standard command on any operating system I'm aware of, so it must be part of some software tool you installed. It would help if you could let us know what tool that is.

Comment: I have downloaded apache-jena-2.11.2.zip from  https://jena.apache.org/download/index.cgi  site and i am using sparql from bat folder inside it

Comment: If possible, add a "Jena" tag to this question, to get the attention of those experts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading your question it is not clear if you want to write some code for your problem or if you just want to use some tool - I'll try to give an answer for the alternative "writing code" as this fits best with stackoverflow:

Roughly speaken you have to load your owl file into a Jena OntModel using one of the methods available in the Jena API. (http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/)
Don't forget to specify the type of reasoning you would like to have.
Then, you could use the ARQ API (http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/) to execute your sparql queries against the OntModel. There should be some code examples on the Jena Homepage also.

If you just want to use some commandline tool provided by Jena, I'm not sure if this allows to specify some reasoning. I would start my search at the tutorial on the Jena documentation site (http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/)

Comment: i am using Jena's commandline tool 'sparql'. I can get the output for simple query(not reasoning based).

 sparql --data demo.owl --query query.text  Using this code i can fire query to my ontology and get the result. But is it any command line command to execute reasoning based query. I understand what you want to say.

Comment: I have posted another question in which i have coded for it after following your suggestion

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516944/filter-not-exists-not-working-with-apache-jena

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is still useful to some reader.

Jena line commands accept [assembler description files](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/assembler/) as input. 'tarql' supports this with [the --desc option](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/cmds.html), so it should be possible to describe a data set backed by an inference model and your data, and then run your query against it.

Another alternative, which is more general and can be applied to any existing endpoint, might be to run [Fuseki](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/) on top of your data and with inference enabled (or any other triple store). Then [use the SPARQL syntax to do federated queries](https://poundblog.wordpress.com/2013/11/06/249/).