# 'FILTER NOT EXISTS ' operator is not working with apache jena?

Tags: sparql, jena

Here my sparql query code is to find Least Common Subsumer and output of query must be 'A'. I am getting blank result here. I think my query is right but seems to be Apache Jena's "filter not exists" is not working. I have also checked with other example. Is there any alternative solution of "filter not exists" or shall i need to modify my java code for that?

**OWL file structure**

```
 Thing:
    |
    A 
    |_P(p1,p2)
      |_M(m1,m2) 
    |
    B
```

Here A,P,M and B are the concepts. p1,p2,m1 and m2 are the instances. M is subclass of P and P is subclass of A. A and B is the subclass of Thing.

**JAVA Code**

```
import org.apache.jena.iri.impl.Main;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.InfModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.Reasoner;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.ReasonerRegistry;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;

public class SPARQLReasoner {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
          sparqlTest();
    }

    public static void sparqlTest() {
        FileManager.get().addLocatorClassLoader(Main.class.getClassLoader());
        Model model;
        model = FileManager.get().loadModel("C:\\Users\\Chetan\\Desktop\\test.owl");
        Reasoner reasoner=ReasonerRegistry.getOWLReasoner();
        reasoner = reasoner.bindSchema(model);
         InfModel infmodel = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, model);
        String queryString;
        queryString = "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> "
                + "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> "
                + "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> "
                + "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> "
                + "PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#> "

                +"SELECT ?lcs WHERE{ " 
                +"?lcs ^(rdf:type/(rdfs:subClassOf)*) :p1 . "
                +"?lcs ^(rdf:type/(rdfs:subClassOf)*) :m1 . "
                +"?lcs rdf:type owl:Class . "

                +"FILTER NOT EXISTS {?llcs ^(rdf:type/(rdfs:subClassOf)*) :p1 . "
                +"?llcs ^(rdf:type/(rdfs:subClassOf)*) :m1 . "
                +"?llcs rdf:type owl:Class . "
                +"?llcs (rdfs:subClassOf)+ ?lcs . "
                +"} "
                +"}";

        Query query= QueryFactory.create(queryString);
        QueryExecution qexec= QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, infmodel);
        try{
            ResultSet results=qexec.execSelect();
            while(results.hasNext()){
                QuerySolution soln=results.nextSolution();
                Resource r;
                r=soln.getResource("lcs");
                System.out.println(r);
            }
        }finally{
            qexec.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**OWL Code:**

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">

    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11"/>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#A"/>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#B"/>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#M">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#P"/>
    </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#P">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#A"/>
    </owl:Class>

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#m1">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#M"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#m2">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#M"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#p1">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#P"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#p2">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#P"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>

</rdf:RDF>
```

Please give your views here.

Comment: Have you tried to validate the query using http://www.sparql.org/query-validator.html ?

Comment: I have done some changes in my query and after i validated it sparql.org/query-validator.html. It is showing correct. I have updated my sparql code just now

Comment: @Joshua But if i want to execute some reasoning based query then i can not do with sparql tool.

Comment: @Chetan Ah, I think I found it (and added an answer).  The problem is that when `?llcs = ?lcs = :P`, the `filter not exists { ?llcs rdfs:subClassOf+ ?lcs }` behaves differently for the raw model and the inference model.  In the raw model, there's no triple `:P rdfs:subClassOf :P`, but in the inference model there is such a triple.  See my answer for how to get around this.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor  I got the expected result. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `filter not exists` works just fine

The `filter not exists` in your query is working just fine.  The problem is that more data exists in the inference model than in the raw model, so there are *more* things that *don't exist* in the raw model than in the inference model.

### This works without an inference model

The expected answer is `:P`.  If you use the (slightly modified) answer from your previous question, [How to get Least common subsumer in ontology using SPARQL Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23510851/1281433), you get the expected results using Jena's `sparql` command line tool:

```sql
prefix :     <http://www.semanticweb.org/chetan/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-11#>
prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ?lcs where {
  ?lcs ^(rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf*) :p1, :m1 ;
       a owl:Class .
  filter not exists { 
    ?llcs ^(rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf*) :p1, :m1 ;
          a owl:Class ;
          rdfs:subClassOf+ ?lcs .
  }
}
```

```
-------
| lcs |
=======
| :P  |
-------
```

### This breaks with an inference model

The query works with a non-inference model, but breaks with an inference model, so the inference model must have some additional data that makes the `filter not exists` fail.  What could change?  In the `filter not exists`, we check that there's no match for:

```
?llcs rdfs:subClassOf+ ?lcs .
```

In the raw data, there's no triple `:P rdfs:subClassOf :P`, so we don't filter out `:P` from the results.  However, with the inference model, we have `x rdfs:subClassOf x` for every class X, and thus we *do* have `:P rdfs:subClassOf :P`, so you get no results.  This will mean that you *never* get a result, so you need to add another filter to make sure that `?llcs` is not the same as `?lcs`:

```
  filter not exists { 
    ?llcs ^(rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf*) :p1, :m1 ;
          a owl:Class ;
          rdfs:subClassOf+ ?lcs .
    filter ( ?llcs != ?lcs )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the latest release?

What do you mean by "blank resource"?

```
            + "SELECT ?lcs" 
            + "WHERE {"
```

will become

```
"SELECT ?lcsWHERE {"
```

The part:

```
soln.getResource("Disease_Observation_List");
```

is null (no variable "Disease_Observation_List").

Comment: I am using apache-jena-2.11.2.zip. I has modified my code according to your suggestion . Still getting blank in result.